# Visual Studio 2010 Crashes after installing SP1 and TFS Preview

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just installed VS2010 SP1 and TFS Preview-KB2581206 and now when I open Visual Studio, I get an error, and suddenly visual studio gets closed.

I checked in event viewer, and found following error there.

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: devenv.exe
P2: 10.0.40219.1
P3: 4d5f2a73
P4: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common
P5: 10.0.0.0
P6: 4f4e3d34
P7: 4b6
P8: 45
P9: System.MissingMethodException
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\Zain\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\Critical_devenv.exe_efc7a99ad144611cef5e929f3abb3eb1973a0_103ff49b

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: a8596dda-0755-11e2-ae04-0022196f9b63
Report Status: 0
```

Any ideas/solutions on how to fix it?

Comment: If TFS Preview hasn't hit RTM yet, chances are it's a bug. What happens if you use an older TFS client?

Comment: earlier I was using codeplex, and it was working awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I still have some issue, but this post helped me at least to kick off visual studio:

[Visual Studio 2010 crashes on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883371/visual-studio-2010-crashes-on-startup)