# Visual Studio 2010 crashes on startup

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

We have been using vs 2010 for years on this machine, (server 2003) and now visual studio  just started crashing on startup.  there is no way to run it at all, it just crashes every time.

I've tried Devenv.exe /SafeMode, resetsettings, etc.  same result.  I've tried re-installing vs2010, I've tried un-installing it and re-installing, same thing.

The event log says it's to do with team foundation server:

---

EventType clr20r3, P1 devenv.exe, P2 10.0.30319.1, P3 4ba1fab3, P4 microsoft.teamfoundation.common, P5 10.0.0.0, P6 502e379e, P7 4b6, P8 45, P9 system.missingmethodexception, P10 NIL.

---

There is also an error with stack trace:

---

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.MissingMethodException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationHost+AuthenticateWorker.WorkCompleted(System.Object, System.Object, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.TfsBackgroundWorkerManager.worker_RunWorkerCompleted(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.AsyncOperationCompleted(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

---

We do use TFS and have had no problems with it.
Any ideas as to why this started happening, and more importantly, 
how can I fix this?  there does not appear to be any way to start visual studio without the tfs component, and we need tfs anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was a windows update that was incompatible with the Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools that were installed.  When I installed the latest version of the power tools, VS stopped crashing.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f

I had removed all of that, but i guess.. who knows...

Answer (score 22):

Following worked for me

1. Close all instances of VS
2. go to [System Drive]:\Users[User Name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0
3. delete all the files and folders from the above folder.

and reopen the VS and everything should be back to normal.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution when all else fails.  If your VS2010 is creating something like this: 

C:\Users\username]\Desktop\Critical_devenv.exe_c7715ea7ca36fe4513ab7bd8b646870441f19e6_18be6400

and inside the "WER" file, if your signatures look like this:
Sig[0].Name=Problem Signature 01
Sig[0].Value=devenv.exe
...
Sig[4].Name=Problem Signature 05
Sig[4].Value=10.0.40219.457
...
Sig[6].Name=Problem Signature 07
Sig[6].Value=4b6
Sig[7].Name=Problem Signature 08
Sig[7].Value=45
Sig[8].Name=Problem Signature 09
Sig[8].Value=System.MissingMethodException

Then do the steps shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstall Power Tool (didn't work)
I install latest Power Tool (didn't work)
I uninstall TFS (it start working)
then I install TFS again (It still working :))

Thanks and by the way detail off error message in windows event log was:

Fault bucket 3292093736, type 5
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: devenv.exe
P2: 10.0.30319.1
P3: 4ba1fab3
P4: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common
P5: 10.0.0.0
P6: 502e379e
P7: 4b6
P8: 45
P9: System.MissingMethodException
P10:

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\rahiljm\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\Critical_devenv.exe_1e501d4117b8b2664a23a63826807fb1d894270_1b9a7992

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: f92dcd0f-91aa-11e2-8682-8c89a571d971
Report Status: 0

Answer (score 1):

I had this very issue after being forced to reinstall Visual Studio 2010 to get BizTalk 2010 ESB working.

I was unable to download KB2581206 as it appears to have no valid content any more. However there is an alternative download which also does the job...

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082

...which is the Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Team Foundation Server Compatibility GDR.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I reinstalled Visual Studio SP1 and uninstalled Net Framework all language packs. After that problem was solved.